# How to add a variable to a MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 URL in a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm following the example on this page 
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/using-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-within-stored-procedure-to-grab-source-of-html-page-and-save-to-table

I need to add a variable to the url. I have tried `id='+ @PMIDLIST '` and also `id='& @PMIDLIST '` but both cause errors. I have also tried
`id=pmidList` but that just does not return a valid response. I have also tried double quotes but that did not work.

These are the errors I got:

> Incorrect syntax near '&'.
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Code:

```
    DECLARE @Object AS INT;
    DECLARE @hr INT
    DECLARE @json AS TABLE (Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))

    DECLARE @pmidList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @PMIDLIST = '17784783,19505939,30166592' 

    EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;

    IF @hr <> 0 
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi? 
     db=pubmed&amp;retmode=json&amp;id='+ @PMIDLIST ' ;out;',
     'false'

    IF @hr <> 0 
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

    IF @hr <> 0 
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT

    IF @hr <> 0
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

    INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) 
        EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'

    -- select the JSON string
    SELECT * FROM @json
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer I needed

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @pmidList NVARCHAR(max)
SET @PMIDLIST = '17784783,19505939,30166592' 

declare @url NVARCHAR(max)
SET @url = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&amp;retmode=json&amp;id='+ @pmidList 

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
       @url OUT,
       'false'
```